# React Jest setInterval test coverage

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to get some test coverage on a functional component.  I have have in useEffect a setInterval to change a message every few seconds. For my test It seems like I am not testing whatever is in useEffect. I've tried `jest.useFakeTimers();`

Also I am setting useState.

component :

```
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import styled from "styled-components";
// Array of strings
import { messages } from "./messages";

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  }
};
`;

const loadMessage = () => {
  // this is the line that is not being tested.
  return messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
};

export const Loader = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Loading...");

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // this is the line that is not being tested.
      setMessage(loadMessage());
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <Wrapper id="login-content">
      <Row className="align-items-center h-100">
        <Col className="col-md-12 mx-auto">
          <div className="container text-center">
            <h1 className="loader" data-testid="loader" aria-live="polite">
              {message}
            </h1>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

test :

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { Loader } from "./Loader";

const doAsync = c => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    c(true);
  }, 3000);
};

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("Loader component", () => {
  it("tests state", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Loader />);
    const message = wrapper.find(".loader").text();

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);

    const callback1 = () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(".loader").text()).not.toMatch(message);
    };

    doAsync(callback1);

    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the problem that your `expect` doesn't necessarily execute? If so you may wish to use `it("tests state", (done) => { ...` and then after your `expect` statement but still inside `callback1`, call `done();`. Also, I'm not familiar with `advanceTimersByTime` but if you care about that I'd expect you want to call it after calling `doAsync`; not sure though.

Comment: Yes, my expect does not execute.  TBH, I am just trying to fine a good way of testing the useState.

Comment: You want to test `useState` or `useEffect`? Or both?

Comment: @WillCain Both.  my test coverage is specifically asking for the setMessage variable but I would like to test both if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumpled upon in Enzymes issues: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2086

> useEffect function does not seem to be executed when the component is
>   rendered with shallow.

given that, what I had to do is mock UseEffect.

```
const doAsync = c => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    c(true);
  }, 3000);
};

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("Loader component", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const useEffect = jest
      .spyOn(React, "useEffect")
      .mockImplementation(f => f());
  });

  it("tests state", done => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Loader />);
    const message = wrapper.find(".loader").text();

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);

    const callback1 = () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(".loader").text()).not.toMatch(message);
    };

    doAsync(callback1);

    jest.useRealTimers();
    done();
  });
});
```

this makes my test pass and I get 100% coverage.

Comment: Nice find. Incidentally, not sure if full (not shallow) rendering is acceptable, but if so perhaps that's another alternative. Also, I'm not sure your `expect` will execute reliably without moving `done()` inside `callback1`, but of course you can verify that with an incorrect `expect` or `console.log` or debugger.

Comment: I followed this example and test passed but I put some logs, I was expecting two to repeat but only showed once. Then changed my test in a way that was supposed to fail but it still passes... Idk why adding the timeout makes a test pass, but definitely not the right answer